# What does the circular cancel sign mean over an Eclipse folder?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have these errors over my target folder. I've tried recompiling, Maven clean, Maven install, rebuilding, etc... they won't go away. Any idea what these mean and why they are appearing?

[image: Screenshot illustrating Eclipse errors.]

Comment: Folder is missing (it does not exist on file system) because it was removed when you cleaned.

Answer (score 0):

The red circular cross usually appears when there is a path error. Use the 'Problems' view to get more information about that specific error.

Also, according to [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46939888/3230030) on Stack Overflow, this error is common when using Maven. They advise to simply right click on the project, go to Maven and select 'Update Project'.